# Form field without entity property in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form type which has a field that is not in the entity as a property, but the entity has a getter and a setter with the same name as form field, explaining:

Form type:

```
$builder->add('theField', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'The field',
    'class' => 'MyAppBundle:AnEntity',
    'empty_value' => '',
));
```

Entity:

```
class User
{
    //There is NOT a property called "theField"

    public function setTheField($value)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function getTheField()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, I'm expected that Symfony2 call the getter and setter to bind and show the form field, but I get this error:

`Property theField does not exists in class My\AppBundle\Entity\User`

Is there a way to create this form field without having the property declared in entity?

**EDIT**

Is strange, but when I declare a private property `theField`, it's works (BTW, that is not what I looking for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$builder->add('theField', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'The field',
    'class' => 'MyAppBundle:AnEntity',
    'empty_value' => '',
    'property_path' => false,
));
```

### Update

Change your field name to the same as attribute in the entity or change `'property_path'` to the attribute name.

```
$builder->add('theField', 'entity', array(
    'label' => 'The field',
    'class' => 'MyAppBundle:AnEntity',
    'empty_value' => '',
    'property_path' => 'theField',
));
```

And in your entity add:

```
private $theField = null;
```

Comment: I'm using 2.0, but, is absolutely necessary to add the property to the entity?

Comment: Yes it's needed. Don't map the property to a doctrine field. Just leave as the definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with the `mapped` option of symfony

```
$builder->add('chooseProduct', ChoiceType::class, array(
             'mapped'=> false,
             'required' => false,
             'placeholder' => 'Choose',
             'choices' => $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:Entity)->getSelectList(),
             'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label')
        ));
```